# Apex error Message doesn't appear on error condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages, list

I have a save method like this, that will prompt on some error condition :

```
public void Save() {
  lstAcct1.clear();
  for(Integer j = 0;j<records.size();j++) {
    if (records[j].Competitor_Product__c==null) {
      ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please select a competitor product'));            
    } else{
      lstAcct1.add(records[j]);
    }
  }
  UpSert lstAcct1;
  records= [select id,Competitor_Product__c,January__c,February__c,March__c,April__c,May__c,June__c,July__c,August__c,September__c,October__c,November__c,December__c from Competitor_Mapping__c where Account__c=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') order by Competitor_Product__c desc];
}
```

On error condition the record is not getting saved, but it does not throw any error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your VF page as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that you didn't include

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

in your VF page. That's the tag that outputs page messages.